# Backpressure in microfluidic devices

Tags: fluid-dynamics, pressure, friction, drag

I am fairly knew to microfluidic and i'm trying to get a better understanding of backpressure in such devices. So far, my understanding is that backpressure originates from **viscous drag** with the wall of the channel and any **changes in the channel section**.

1. Is it correct and what could be **other sources** of backpressure in such devices ?
2. What are the usual ways of computing it (loss by pipe friction formulas... ) ?

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

other sources of backpressure in microfluidic devices include:

1) inertial effects (acceleration of fluid mass elements)

2) externally-applied static backpressure (as applied by elastic elements in the fluid reservoir)

Lumped-element flow equations work well enough for approximate solutions, but better than two-place accuracy requires finite element analysis of the flow system, and must include inertial and surface-tension effects for any free surfaces. steady-state flow modeling will yield grossly incorrect results.